# change default scan program in indicator-session-applet

Tags: indicator

I'd like to remove the default scan program simple scan which is called in the indicator-session applet, and replace it with my favorite scan program, xsane. I can't find any hints how to achieve that. When simple scan is removed from the computer, ubuntu wants me to reinstall it via software center.

Where and how could I change that?

so long

hanky

EDIT

I think I found a solution after examining the source code.

The only way to change it seems to be a recompling of the package after editing src/device-menu-mgr.c and replacing all occurences of 'simple_scan' with 'xsane' there.

I really can't believe this is hard-coded - no choice for the user...

Comment: what Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10, 64-bit, but I found the answer, see edit above

Comment: Please come back tomorrow and add your edit as an answer - you should accept it via the "tick" button.  This will also allow us to upvote you so you gain reputation (rep).  thanks.

Comment: OK, I thought it might be easier this way... I tried yesterday, but was informed that I couldn't do so immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution after examining the source code.

The only way to change it seems to be a recompiling of the package after editing src/device-menu-mgr.c and replacing all occurences of 'simple_scan' with 'xsane' there.

I really can't believe this is hard-coded - no choice for the user...

so long

hank